# PHP PDO num_rows issue

Tags: php, pdo

When I'm trying to log in using an existing account the code runs OK but when I attempt to log in with an non-existent account it should do the `else` part and `echo` the message but it still does the part defined in the `if` block. Why?

Any other tips are welcome

```
$sql = "SELECT email,password,id FROM user WHERE email=? AND password=?";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($email,$password));
$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$number_of_rows = $stm->fetchColumn();

if(count($number_of_rows)==1){
    $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
    header('Location: cpanel/#welcome');
}else{
    echo "<font style='background-color: #F9C5CA'>Error: Your email and/or password are incorrect. Please try again.</font>";
}
```

Comment: Where does `$email` and `$password` come from?

Comment: Check `$number_of_rows` - what does it contain?

Comment: `$number_of_rows` contains the e-mail if there's a match... Counting it looks like a strange step.

Comment: From here $email = $_POST['email']; $password=md5($_POST['password']); @Jueecy.new

Comment: @jtheman: from your link: `PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.` -> Doesn't work for `SELECT` statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchColumn()` does not count the number of rows, it returns a specific column value from the next record in the result set (or `false` if you are at the end of your result set). If you are using MySQL you can use `rowCount()` to count the rows in the result set (this method is not supported for `SELECT` statements across all database types however).

Alternately, since it seems you only care about one row being returned, you can simply evaluate the value of `$row`.  If it is `false` then you didn't get a record returned. I might suggest adding an explicit `LIMIT 1` to your query so it is clear to the reader of the code that only 0 or 1 records could ever be returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

There is a beautiful function in PDO called `rowCount()` you should use it, to know if your query is returning any rows, in this case, `1` for true or `0` false.

You can use it like;

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  user, pass FROM foo WHERE username =? 
                         AND password = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($user,$pass));
```

Now, to the count.

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){echo 'username found';}else {
echo 'wrong login details.';
}
```

Comment: he shouldn't use this function

Comment: @YourCommonSense Care to tell us *WHY NOT*. That is how an argument usually works, incase you haven't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) `fetchColumn()` returns a string therefore `count` will always return `1`. What you really need is [`PDOStatement::rowCount`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
$stm->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You don't need no additional verifications if you already have your data

So, checking `$row` would be enough.
However, requesting email and password (which you have already) makes no sense either.
So, you can use fetchColumn(), but without fetch then:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE email=? AND password=?";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($email,$password));
$id = $stm->fetchColumn();

if ($id) {
    $_SESSION['id']=$id;
    header('Location: cpanel/#welcome');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<font style='background-color: #F9C5CA'>Error: Your email and/or password are incorrect.  Please try again.</font>";
}
```